# Handle target="_blank" in webview in swift

Tags: url, uiwebview, swift4

I am implementing a webview for loading contents from a URL in my app using web view. I want that url with target="_blank" should open in browser or else open in app only.

I am using

```
url = NSURL (string: "\(urlBase)\(response![0].Message ?? "")")!
            let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
            webVFAI.loadRequest(requestObj)
```

this opens url in app but I want if my url contains target ="_blank", it should open it in browser. How to handle this?
Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. I just checked for my pageid to decide whether to open url in browser or in app
I used shouldStartLoadWith function

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if(condition) {
    switch navigationType {
    case .linkClicked:
        guard let url = request.url else { return true }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
        return false // opens in browser
    default:
        return true // opens in app
    }
  }
    return true;
}
```